# Scala - divide the dataset into dataset of arrays with a fixed size

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a function whose purpose is to divide a dataset into arrays of a given size.
For example - I have a dataset with 123 objects of the Foo type, I provide to the function arraysSize 10 so as a result I will have a Dataset[Array[Foo]] with 12 arrays with 10 Foo's and 1 array with 3 Foo.
Right now function is working on collected data - I would like to change it on dataset based because of performance but I dont know how.
This is my current solution:

```
  private def mapToFooArrays(data: Dataset[Foo],
                                         arraysSize: Int): Dataset[Array[Foo]]= {
data.collect().grouped(arraysSize).toSeq.toDS()
  }
```

The reason for doing this transformation is because the data will be sent in the event. Instead of sending 1 million events with information about 1 object, I prefer to send, for example, 10 thousand events with information about 100 objects

Comment: What's the purpose of having a `Dataset[Array[_]]`? Depending on what you want to achieve, the solution might be very different. I'm thinking at `repartition`, or maybe Window functions...

Comment: The reason for doing this transformation is because the data will be sent in the event. Instead of sending 1 million events with information about 1 object, I prefer to send, for example, 10 thousand events with information about 100 objects

Comment: If you don't care about exact number per event, I would go for using partitions assuming you have a rough idea of the number of data you're dealing with.

Comment: Otherwise maybe I would go with a totally different solution, not involving Spark but more a streaming solution that reads on HDFS and send events. Something like Akka Streams, ZIO Stream...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, this is a weird use case. I can not think of any efficient solution to do this, as it is going to require a lot of shuffling no matter how we do it.

But, the following is still better, as it avoids collecting to the driver node and will thus be more scalable.

Things to keep in mind -

- what is the value of `data.count()` ?
- what is the size of a single `Foo` ?
- what is the value of `arraySize` ?
- what is your executor configuration ?

Based on these factors you will be able to come up with the `desiredArraysPerPartition` value.

```scala
val desiredArraysPerPartition = 50

private def mapToFooArrays(
    data: Dataset[Foo],
    arraysSize: Int
): Dataset[Array[Foo]] = {
  val size = data.count()
  val numArrays = (size.toDouble / arrarySize).ceil
  val numPartitions = (numArrays.toDouble / desiredArraysPerPartition).ceil
  
  data
    .repartition(numPartitions)
    .mapPartitions(_.grouped(arrarySize).map(_.toArray))
}
```

After reading the edited part, I think that `100 size` in `10 thousand events with information about 100 objects` is not really important. As it is referred as `about 100`. There can be more than one events with less than `100 Foo's`.

If we are not very strict about that `100` size, then there is no need of reshuffle.

We can locally `group` the `Foo's` present in each of the partitions. As this grouping is being done `locally` and `not globally`, this might result in more than one (potentially one for each partition) `Arrays` with less than 100 `Foo's`.

```scala
private def mapToFooArrays(
    data: Dataset[Foo],
    arraysSize: Int
): Dataset[Array[Foo]] = 
  data
    .mapPartitions(_.grouped(arrarySize).map(_.toArray))
```

Comment: I edited the question : reason for doing this transformation is because the data will be sent in the event. Instead of sending 1 million events with information about 1 object, I prefer to send, for example, 10 thousand events with information about 100 objects

Comment: Why is the reason important ? It will not change the answer unless you change the requirement. The real question is - Is that `100` size limit important ?